# Double to Float array conversion and Endian swap

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write code to convert a binary file which contains `double` values in big-endian, into a second file which contains `float` values in little-endian.

I separated the task into two segments and I did the endian conversion successfully first, as seen below. My first question is:

- Sometimes a "Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped)" error was coming up. I dont know why, but I managed to solve it by changing the data type of the array `A` from `int` to `char`. When I tried to define another file name for the second `fopen()` (I wanted to replace "source" with "destination") the same error occurred. The same happens when I try to insert another array named `C`. Do you know why is this happening? I dont find it logical to come up errors because of the names!
- My second question is: I tried to type cast the `A` array and to convert the data type from `char` to `float`, but I had no luck. Then I thought of writing the `A` array into a file again and read from the new file per 64 bits. Then I would change this double (64-bits) into float, but I dont know how. Could help me with this?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{

FILE *source;
int i;
int size=6000000;
int sof=5960000;  // size of file in bytes
char A [size];
char temp [10];
char C [size];


source=fopen("/home/yannis/Endian/TrxVU_9k6.raw","r");
fread(A,sof,1,source);
fclose(source);

printf("\nEvery field of A-array corresponds to %i Byte!\n\n",sizeof(A[0]));  // check

for (i=0; i<=size; i+=8)  // Endian swap - Data type=Double
{
    temp[0]=A[i+7];
    temp[1]=A[i+6];
    temp[2]=A[i+5];
    temp[3]=A[i+4];
    A[i+7]=A[i];
    A[i+6]=A[i+1];
    A[i+5]=A[i+2];
    A[i+4]=A[i+3]; 
    A[i+3]=temp[3];
    A[i+2]=temp[2];
    A[i+1]=temp[1];
    A[i]=temp[0];
}

source=fopen("/home/yannis/Endian/Little_TrxVU_9k6.raw","w");
fwrite(A,sof,1,source);
fclose(source);

//source=fopen("/home/yannis/Endian/Little_TrxVU_9k6.raw","r");
//fread(C,1,sof,source);
//fclose(source);
}
```

Comment: For the int to char change producing no segmentation faults: a char is always 1 byte in C; the size of an int is dependent on, for example, your architecture (could 2 or 4 bytes, for example). So char is the correct type to use if you want to read the separate bytes (as you want to do here).

Comment: As for going to float, things will become more complicated. My suggestion would be to create a pointer to a double, step through your array in steps of 8, assign the pointer to double to a pointer of that char array at the current step (`p_double = &A[8*i]`), and now you have a double if you dereference `*p_double`. Cast that to float, and save the floats into your file. This assumes your current architecture is small endian.

Comment: Thanks @Evert I will try it as soon as possoble!

Answer (score 1):

Why does it segfault? This line:

```
for (i=0; i<=size; i+=8)  // Endian swap - Data type=Double
```

Maybe you mean i < size. With i <= size, you will end up accessing elements A[size] .. A[size + 7], which are outside of the array, and doing this probably corrupts the program's memory.

You can often trace segfaults by running the program in a debugger. That should tell you which address caused the segfault, and that helps you figure out what happened.

There's also a mismatch between "sof" and "size" (shouldn't they be the same?) and you should really check for errors after calls to fopen, fread and fwrite, in order to be sure that the program really did what you expected. For instance, did fread *really* read as much data as you expected.

Comment: First of all I thought that i<=size and i<size would be the same, but obviously you have a point! 
Regarding debugger, I use the linux terminal to run my code and I read that there is no pre-instal debugger and I didnt have time to research more on this.
About size and sof, I prefferred to set size a little more than sof in order to not face any trouble with the dimensions, but sure I could set them at the same length.